# Android : How to save an Object class in bundle before screen rotate?

Tags: android-activity

```
package com.explorateurfichier;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

public class PileFile
{
    private int pos; // position dans le tableau
    private File [] p;

`public PileFile () // creation d’une pile vide de taille 10
{
    p = new File[10];
    pos = -1;
}

public PileFile (int taille) // creation d’un pile vide de taille donnee
{
    p = new File[taille];
    pos = -1;
}

public void empile (File file)
{
    if (pos == p.length) { // plus d’expace
        File[] tmp = new File[p.length+10];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
            tmp[i] = p[i];
        p = tmp;
    }
    p[++pos] = file;
}

public File depile ()
{
    return p[pos--];
}

public File sommet ()
{
    return p[pos];
}

public boolean estVide ()
{
    return pos < 0;
}`

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way is to have your class implement either `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can put an instance into a `Bundle`.

However, since your class contains `File` objects, you might be better off using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` (deprecated, but still available) or the Fragment API `setRetainInstance()` instead. In this way, you won't need to serialize/deserialize the object. You just give a reference to the object to Android, which holds on to it while your Activity is destroyed and recreated, and then you can get it back.